# Django simple pagination in detail view between items

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-views

I want to add simple back/next pagination in my item detail view.

How can I do that ?

I have something like that in my template:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="#back">Back</a>
                {% endif %}

                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="#next">Next: {{ item.title }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

The main thing is that I want to do this in ItemDetailView, not in ItemListView, because in list view I have all items, and I just want to go between items in detail view.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you want pagination in a detail view. Do you simply want links to the next and previous objects?
What is your model? If you are ordering by a date field, then it will have [`get_previous_by_foo`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO) and [`get_next_by_foo`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO) methods.

Comment: What do you class as the next and previous objects? By id? get_context_data would be the best place to set the value for these links, but it depends on how you want to class the next and previous objects. (I don't think pagination is really the correct word for what you are trying to achieve - pagination implies a list.)

Comment: You could always use a list view with paginate_by set to 1.